# Checkbox React event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Добрый день, не могу понять в чем проблема с функцией `targetSortElement`, по сути эта функция должна конкатить и слайсить выбранные чекбоксы, но оно мне все время обнуляет мой массив, и записывает только 1 выбранный элемент в массив, помогите разобраться:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isChecked: false,
            selectedItems: [],
        };
        this.targetSortElement = this.targetSortElement.bind(this);
    }

    targetSortElement(e) {
        const newSelection = e.target.value;
        let newSelectionArray;
        if(this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(newSelection) > -1) {
            newSelectionArray = this.state.selectedItems.filter(s => s !== newSelection);
        } else {
            newSelectionArray = [...this.state.selectedItems, newSelection];
            console.log(newSelectionArray)
        }
        this.setState({ selectedItems: newSelectionArray });
    }
    render() {
        return(
                    <div className="list-view">
                        <div className="table-list list-invite">
                            <input key={item.id} s={12} name={item.name} type='checkbox' value={item.name} label=' ' defaultChecked={this.state.isChecked} onChange={(event) => {
                                this.targetSortElement(event)
                            }} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
        )
    }
}

export  default Products;
```

Вот что получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Будто не видит this.state.selectedItems в функции targetSortElement

Comment: Кажется, что проблема где-то во вне. Т.к. данный компонент работает именно так как и ожидается. https://jsfiddle.net/x3ocuLs1/ .